# How to take get parameters for sorting items by category in Yii2?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, yii2

I use Yii2 advanced template. In my database table I have items with `categry` field (from 1.. to inf)

Controller action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new AdsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => '_item_view',,
]) ?>
```

I have enabled prettyUrl

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
```

And .htaccess in frontend/web/

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

1) How can I show items that were find only by category?
Now mysite.com/items shows all items with mixed categories
I want to make mysite.com/items/cat/1 or mysite.com/items/1 that will show categories with `category = 1`

2) Is there any article how to make mysite.com/items/category-name-url instead number? I store category names in `$app->params`. Next item page with `id = 5` will be mysite.com/items/category-name-url/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In config in `urlManager` put:

`'items/cat/<id:\d+>' => '{YOUR_CONTROLLER}/{YOUR_ACTION}',`

In `controller` like that:

```
public function actionIndex($id) // yii2 provide $id form url
    {                         

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => AdsSearch::find()->where(['category' => $id]),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'category' => $category
        ]);
    }
```

2) In config in `urlManager` put:

`'items/<category>' => '{YOUR_CONTROLLER}/{YOUR_ACTION}',`

In `controller`

```
$subCategory = Yii::$app->request->get('category');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => AdsSearch::find()->where(['categoryUrl' => $subCategory]),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'category' => $category
        ]);
```

Or in my projects like that `Category` and `Goods` models:

```
$category = Category::findOne(['url' => $subCategory]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Goods::find()->where(['categoryId' => $category->id])->with('mainPhoto'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'category' => $category
        ]);
```